# C++/WinRT Return IVector<SomeStruct> to C# application

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm attempting to return a list of structs from C++/WinRT to C#. The error message I get is: The stub received bad data.

IDL:

```
namespace SampleComponents
{
    [version(1.0)]
    struct DateTimeInfo
    {
        Int32 Year;
        Int32 Month;
        Int32 Day;
        Int32 Hour;
        Int32 Minute;
        Int32 Second;
        Int32 Milliseconds;
    };

    [version(1.0)]
    struct SampleStruct
    {
        String Name;
        DateTimeInfo Created;
        Int64 Amount;
    };

    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass SampleRetrieval : ISampleRetrieval
    {
        SampleRetrieval();
    }

    [version(1.0)]
    [uuid(aa11a991-7a39-4278-973b-9a73776d6519)]
    interface ISampleRetrieval : IInspectable
    {

        HRESULT GetSamples([out, retval] Windows.Foundation.Collections.IVector<SampleStruct>** result);

    }

}
```

SampleComponents.h:

```cpp
#include "SampleComponents.g.h"

using namespace winrt::SampleComponents;

namespace winrt::SampleComponents::implementation
{

    struct SampleRetrieval : SampleRetrievalT<SampleRetrieval>
    {
        SampleRetrieval() {

        };

        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<SampleStruct> GetSamples() const;
        
    };


}

namespace winrt::SampleComponents::factory_implementation
{
    struct SampleRetrieval : SampleRetrievalT<SampleRetrieval, implementation::SampleRetrieval>
    {
    };

}
```

SampleComponents.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "SampleComponents.h"

using namespace winrt;

namespace winrt::SampleComponents::implementation
{

    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<SampleStruct> SampleRetrieval::GetSamples() const
    {
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<SampleStruct> items{ winrt::single_threaded_vector<SampleStruct>() };
        do
        {
            ... GET DATA ...

            SampleStruct sample;

            ... FILL SAMPLE DATA ...

            items.Append(sample);

        } while (... CONDITION ...);


        return items;
    }

}
```

When I call SampleRetrieval.GetSamples() from C# is when I get the exception.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I've tried many different ways and cannot get this working.

Comment: I implement a C++/WinRT Component with the IDL code you give, then use a C# project to reference the component and successfully call the `GetSamples()` method in C# without encountering the error message: *The stub received bad data.* Could you give it a try to see if the issue is specific to this code?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes. After trying this specifically, I found out that my error is actually from an RPC call. It just didn't seem like that because RPC worked all the way up to the last item in my list before failing. So it seemed like it was a result of me returning the value.